# "Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined at" in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to make an e-commerce website by following the guide of Dennis Ivy in YouTube. But in applying some logic in the checkout form, I've been facing an error that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined at".

[["Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined at" in the console]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1B2q.png)

What I want to do is remove the 'user-info' if the user is not "AnonymousUser". And remove the 'form' if you don't need to ship the products (digital) and the user is not "AnonymousUser" to only show the 'payment-info'.

Here's the checkout.html code:

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="box-element" id="form-wrapper">
            <form id="form">
                <div id="user-info">
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input required class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div id="shipping-info">
                    <hr>
                    <p>Shipping Information:</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address..">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City..">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state" placeholder="State..">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip code..">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="country" placeholder="Zip code..">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr>
                <input id="form-button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Continue">
            </form>
        </div>

        <br>
        <div class="box-element hidden" id="payment-info">
            <small>Paypal Options</small>
            <button id="make-payment">Make Payment</button>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="box-element">
            <a  class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'cart' %}">&#x2190; Back to Cart</a>
            <hr>
            <h3>Order Summary</h3>
            <hr>
            {% for item in items %}
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
                    <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>₱{{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>x{{item.quantity}}</p></div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <h5>Items:   {{order.get_cart_items}}</h5>
            <h5>Total:   ₱{{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2}}</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var shipping = '{{order.shipping}}'

    if(shipping == 'False'){
        document.getElementById('shipping-info').innerHTML = ''
    }

    if (user != 'AnonymousUser'){
        document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = ''
    }

    if (shipping == 'False' && user != 'AnonymousUser'){
        //Hide entire form if user is logged in and shipping is false
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper').classList.add('hidden');
        //Show payment if logged in user wants to buy an item that does not require shipping
        document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove('hidden');
    }

    var form = document.getElementById('form')
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('Form Submitted...')
        document.getElementById('form-button').classList.add("hidden");
        document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove("hidden");
    })

    document.getElementById('make-payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        submitFormData()
    })

    function submitFormData(){
        console.log('Payment button clicked')
    }

</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

Here's the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url 
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in orderitems:
            if i.product.digital == False:
                shipping = True
        return shipping

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

Here's the views.py file:

```
from itertools import product
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
import json

def store(request): 

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items

    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping': False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products, 'items':items, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items

    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping': False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def checkout(request):
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items

    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping': False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)

def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

**I think the JavaScript at the bottom of checkout.html is asking for the user in this part:**

```
var shipping = '{{order.shipping}}'

    if(shipping == 'False'){
        document.getElementById('shipping-info').innerHTML = ''
    }

    if (user != 'AnonymousUser'){
        document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = ''
    }

    if (shipping == 'False' && user != 'AnonymousUser'){
        //Hide entire form if user is logged in and shipping is false
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper').classList.add('hidden');
        //Show payment if logged in user wants to buy an item that does not require shipping
        document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove('hidden');
    }
```

How can I get rid of that error and apply the logic that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you did in your view, the way to check to see if a user is anonymous or not is to use the `request.user.is_authenticated`, instead of checking to see if the user equals the *string* 'AnonymousUser'.  So replace all instances of `if user != 'AnonymousUser':` in your HTML and JavaScript with `if request.user.is_authenticated` or perhaps even `user.is_authenticated`.  Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#attributes) on this.

Now as far as the new error, it might just mean you're using the wrong syntax in the Javascript.  Here's how it needs to be done (this is only an example, you'll need to replace all instances like this one:

```js
if ({% request.user.is_authenticated %}){
        document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = ''
    }
```

Note the `{%   %}` to tell Django to replace the contents within with the variable, in this case `request.user.is_authenticated`.

Comment: I tried to use that but new error showed up that says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Comment: @EmilioBillionario, I've edited my answer to address your new error.

Comment: Thank you so much @raphael, it worked! But I just made some few changes like using "var user = '{{request.user.is_authenticated}}' instead so that there will be no complications in my last condition where I use "&&". Thank again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. 

> 

---

**In checkout.html change the AnonymousUser to the user !=' False' it will work.**

var shipping = '{{order.shipping}}'
    var total = '{{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2}}'

    

        if(shipping == 'False'){
            document.getElementById('shipping-info').innerHTML = ''
        }
        **if (user != "False")**{
            document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = ''
            
        }
        **if (shipping == 'False' && user == "True")**{
            //Hide entire form if user is logged in and shipping is false
            document.getElementById('form-wrapper').classList.add('hidden');
            //Show payment if logged in user wants to buy an item that does not require shipping
            document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove('hidden');
        }
        
        


    var form = document.getElementById('form')
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('Form Submitted...')
        document.getElementById('form-button').classList.add("hidden");
        document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove("hidden");
    })

    document.getElementById('make-payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        submitFormData()
    })
    function submitFormData(){
        console.log('Payment button clicked')}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).